# React, Redux, RBAC, Авторизация по ролям

Tags: reactjs, redux, rbac

Помогите решить такую задачу, пожалуйста. Я делаю проект, там есть личный кабинет пользователя. У пользователей есть свои роли, например менеджер, покупатель и админ. Написан Api для сайта, Api возвращает роль пользователся исходя из отправленным ему jwt токеном. Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы после авторизации каждый пользователь попал в свой личный кабинет. У каждой роли свой личный кабинет и они категорически отличаются. пожалуйста помогите

Comment: сделать редирект

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы должны создать для каждого компонента 3 суб компоненты. Допустим у нас есть компонент `Dashboard` у нас должен быть 3 компоненты и ме должны рендерить то что нужен.

```
getDashboardComponent(user){
   switch(user.role){
       case: "ADMIN": return <DashboardForAdmin />;
       case: "USER": return <DashboardForUser />;
       ...

    }
}
...
....
<Route path={'/dashboard'} component={getDashboardComponent()} />
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас попробую, если что, напишу